# Integrate liferay 7.4 recaptcha with MVC Portlet and apache wicket

Tags: liferay, wicket

I have an old application uses wicket 1.4 and want to integrate the liferay reCAPTCHA ( liferay 7.4).

Is there any guide for that?
Or anyone might help ?

It worked for MVC portlet like the following but still cannot achieve same in wicket :

Use CAPTCHA or reCAPTCHA with custom portlet in Liferay MVC Portlet:

CAPTCHA is a “Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart”. It is used in the computer world to determine whether an end-user is human or non-human. Liferay provides the necessary API as well as tag library to implement CAPTCHA in your custom portlet. Also, you can integrate Google reCAPTCHA in your custom portlet.

**Prerequisites**

**Java
Liferay portal 7/7.x**

**Use CAPTCHA in custom portlet**

Assuming you’ve already created a Liferay-workspace project

Follow below steps to implement CAPTCHA in your custom portlet

1. Create MVC Portlet
   Go to liferay workspace project → modules → new
   Select other → Liferay → Liferay Module Project and Click on Next
   Enter project name
   Select “Project Template Name” as “mvc-portlet” and Click on “Next”
   Enter Package name and Click on “Finish”
   The necessary file structure for MVC module will get created as below :

[image]

**2) Now we add below code in view.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="/init.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/captcha" prefix="liferay-captcha" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.captcha.CaptchaTextException"%>

<portlet:actionURL name="basicFormDataWithCaptcha" var="basicFormDataWithCaptchaAActionURL" />
<portlet:resourceURL id="captcha" var="captchaResourceURL"/>

<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CaptchaTextException.class %>"  message="captcha-verification-failed" />
<aui:form method="post" name="basicForm" action="<%= basicFormDataWithCaptchaAActionURL %>">
    <aui:input name="firstName" >
        <aui:validator name="alpha"/>
    </aui:input>
    <aui:input name="lastName" >
        <aui:validator name="alpha"/>
    </aui:input> 
    <liferay-captcha:captcha url="<%= captchaResourceURL %>"/>
    <aui:button type="submit" value="Submit"></aui:button>
</aui:form>
```

[image]

**3) Create Action method in CustomCaptchaPortlet**

package ...;

import ...;

@Component(
...
)
public class CustomCaptchaPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

```
private Log log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(this.getClass().getName());

@ProcessAction(name = "basicFormDataWithCaptcha")
public void basicFormDataWithCaptcha(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

    String firstName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"firstName");
    String lastName=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"lastName");
    log.info("First Name : " + firstName);
    log.info("Last Name : " + lastName);

    try{
        CaptchaUtil.check(actionRequest);
        log.info("CAPTCHA verification successful.");
    }catch(Exception exception) {
        if(exception instanceof CaptchaTextException) {
            SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, exception.getClass(), exception);
            log.error("CAPTCHA verification failed.");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse)
    throws  IOException, PortletException {
    try {
        CaptchaUtil.serveImage(resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
    }catch(Exception exception) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }
}

protected boolean isCheckMethodOnProcessAction() {
    return _CHECK_METHOD_ON_PROCESS_ACTION;
}
private static final boolean _CHECK_METHOD_ON_PROCESS_ACTION = false;}
```

[image]

**Output with CAPTCHA**

[image]

**Use Google reCAPTCHA in custom portlet**
To integrate Google reCAPTCHA in Liferay please follow below steps

**1) Get Site key & Secret key from Google reCAPTCHA**
Go to [www.google.com/recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) in your web browser
Click on “Admin console” button (Located at top-right corner)
Fill up your details in the form and then click on “Submit”

[image]

**4- You will get “Site key & Secret key” as below image. This you will require while configuring Google reCAPTCHA with Liferay**

[image]

**2) Enable Google reCAPTCHA in your Liferay**
Login as admin user
Navigate to Control Panel → System Setting → SECURITY → Security Tools  → CAPTCHA

Go to CAPTCHA Engine and change it to reCAPTCHA

Enter “reCAPTCHA public key” and “reCAPTCHA private key”
You need to enter the values you got from Google reCAPTCHA site in previse step , “reCAPTCHA public key” field, and “secret key” in “reCAPTCHA private key” field
Click on ‘Save’

[image]

**To test Google reCAPTCHA is properly configured or not**. Logout from Liferay and go to Create Account page. You can see a default Liferay CAPTCHA is replaced with the new Google reCAPTCHA

[image]

**3) Use Google reCAPTCHA in your Custom Portlet**

Once you configure reCAPTCHA from control panel below, code will render google reCAPTCHA

<liferay-captcha:captcha url="<%= captchaResourceURL %>"/>

If we configure reCAPTCHA from Liferay control panel, Output of above ‘custom-captcha-portlet’ will look like below

[image]

---

As you see it works for MVC portlet but I have some code written in apache wicket which I did not find a way to achieve same and wondering if there is a way to integrate Liferay reCAPTCHA with wicket somehow ?

Comment: Please see [help/on-topic] and [ask], provide us with a starting point (e.g. what have you already tried, which problem are you running into?) and edit your question to make it on-topic for stackoverflow. As it is, you're asking for generic documentation, which is explicitly off topic

Comment: Also, please [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)